# Odoo 16, odoo Change the value of my " fields.Text " from function

Tags: python, odoo-16

## Here is my code, i want to change value of "product_allowed_lines = fields.Text()" from onchange_command_draft() but the value don't change.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api from odoo.exceptions import UserError import json

class Support(models.Model):
    _name = 'assurance_medicaments.support'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']

    product_allowed_lines = fields.Text()
    command_draft = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='sale.order', string="Commande", domain="[('partner_id', '=', customer_id), ('state', 'in', ['draft'])]", required=True)


@api.onchange('command_draft')
def onchange_command_draft(self):
    if self.command_draft:
        product_allowed_lines_tmp = []
        for line in self.command_draft.order_line:
                order_line_values = {
                    'product_id': line.product_id.id,
                    'product_uom_qty': line.product_uom_qty,
                    'price_unit': line.price_unit
                    # Other order line fields you wish to define
                }
                product_allowed_lines_tmp.append(order_line_values)
        if product_allowed_lines_tmp:
            self.product_allowed_lines = json.dumps(product_allowed_lines_tmp)`
```

## When i want to take value of self.product_allowed_lines from another function, i get bool response

`self.product_allowed_lines = json.dumps(product_allowed_lines_tmp)`